# Relation type in Model is not defined

Tags: prisma

I am new to Prisma.
I am trying to use Prisma with Nextjs.
But I am facing problems with one to many relations.

I have a schema like below.

```
model Thread {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement()) @unique
    title String
    kakikoes Kakiko[]
}

model Kakiko {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement()) @unique
    thread Thread @relation(fields: [threadId], references: [id])
    threadId Int
}
// Kakiko means "Post" in Japanese.
```

There is "one to many Relation" which towards "kakiko" from Thread.

I can get datas from DB and I can send datas to browser, But My TS compiler says "TS2339: Property 'kakikoes' does not exist on type 'Thread'."

```
await prisma.thread.findUnique({
        where: {
          id: threadId
        },
        include: {
          kakikoes: true
        }
      })
```

```
 {thread.kakikoes.map(kakiko => <p>{kakiko.body}</p>)}
```

I checked type definition, and kakikoes not defined.

```
/**
 * Model Thread
 * 
 */
export type Thread = {
  id: number
  itaId: number
  title: string
}
```

How can I solve this?
Thank you.

---

Added (2022/04/03)
I use Intelij Idea Ultimate.
[image: picture of the ERROR]

Type is defined like this.

[image]

My code is working correctly on My browser And Nextjs dev Tool doesnt say Any Errors nor Any Warnings.

Comment: where is TypeScript throwing that error? When building your project or developing? Prisma does not include relations on generated types because relations are not returned from queries by default.

Answer (score 0):

The model is correct. I have tried it and this is the working solution.

schema.prisma file

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Thread {
  id       Int      @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  title    String
  kakikoes Kakiko[]
}

model Kakiko {
  id       Int    @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  thread   Thread @relation(fields: [threadId], references: [id])
  threadId Int
}
```

main.ts file

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function main() {
  // ... you will write your Prisma Client queries here

  await prisma.kakiko.create({
    data: {
      thread: {
        create: {
          title: 'test',
        },
      },
    },
  });

  const thread = await prisma.thread.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: 1,
    },
    include: {
      kakikoes: true,
    },
  });

  console.log('thread', thread);
}

main()
  .catch((e) => {
    throw e;
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  });
```

Here is the response

```js
thread { id: 1, title: 'test', kakikoes: [ { id: 1, threadId: 1 } ] }
```

Attaching the image as well:

[image: Prisma]

I would also suggest restarting your [vs code typescript compiler](https://tinytip.co/tips/vscode-restart-ts/) which could cause this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But I am using InteliJ IDEA Ultimamte.
I restared my IDEA But This Err shown again.

I attached the image at above.